# Unity - Aim Line (Line Renderer) not showing in 2D shooter

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, 2d-games, raycasting

I'm a Unity novice and I'm creating a small 2D shooting game on a school project and I already managed to have a functional shooting system in the main character that even bounces off some objects using Unity Physics.

I now wanted to integrate an aim line that will predict the trajectory of the bullet, including the bounces on objects (bubble-shooter style).

I found a script that uses Raycast and Line Renderer and it supposedly does this and I tried to integrate it into my gun script but although it does not give any error, it simply does not show anything when I test the game. I do not know if the problem is in the settings that I put in the Line Renderer Component or it is in the Script.

Could someone help me understand where my error is and point the right way?

My goal is:

[image: Game idea]

My Line Renderer Component Definitions:

[image: Line Renderer Definitions]

My Weapon Script:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
[Range(1, 5)]
[SerializeField] private int _maxIterations = 3;
[SerializeField] private float _maxDistance = 10f;

public int _count;
public LineRenderer _line;

public Transform Firepoint;
public GameObject BulletPrefab;
public GameObject FirePrefab;

void Start()
{
    _line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
{
  if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }

    _count = 0;
    _line.SetVertexCount(1);
    _line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
    _line.enabled = RayCast(new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward));
}

void Shoot()
{
    //shooting logic
    var destroyBullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation);
    Destroy(destroyBullet, 10f);
    var destroyFire = Instantiate(FirePrefab, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation);
    Destroy(destroyFire, 0.3f);
}

private bool RayCast(Ray ray)
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, _maxDistance) && _count <= _maxIterations - 1)
    {
        _count++;
        var reflectAngle = Vector3.Reflect(ray.direction, hit.normal);
        _line.SetVertexCount(_count + 1);
        _line.SetPosition(_count, hit.point);
        RayCast(new Ray(hit.point, reflectAngle));
        return true;
    }
    _line.SetVertexCount(_count + 2);
    _line.SetPosition(_count + 1, ray.GetPoint(_maxDistance));
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity has two physics engines one for 2D and one for 3D. The script you provided relies on the 3D physics engine and won't work for 2D colliders. I edited your script to function with 2D colliders.

Either way make sure that all your game objects use the same physics system. Also the original script only shows the line renderer if it hits something. Best of luck!

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 5)]
    [SerializeField] private int _maxIterations = 3;

    [SerializeField] private float _maxDistance = 10f;

    public int _count;
    public LineRenderer _line;

    public Transform Firepoint;
    public GameObject BulletPrefab;
    public GameObject FirePrefab;

    private void Start()
    {
        _line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }

        _count = 0;
        _line.SetVertexCount(1);
        _line.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        _line.enabled = true;
        RayCast(transform.position, transform.up);
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        //shooting logic
        var destroyBullet = Instantiate(BulletPrefab, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation);
        Destroy(destroyBullet, 10f);
        var destroyFire = Instantiate(FirePrefab, Firepoint.position, Firepoint.rotation);
        Destroy(destroyFire, 0.3f);
    }

    private bool RayCast(Vector2 position, Vector2 direction)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(position, direction, _maxDistance);
        if (hit && _count <= _maxIterations - 1)
        {
            _count++;
            var reflectAngle = Vector2.Reflect(direction, hit.normal);
            _line.SetVertexCount(_count + 1);
            _line.SetPosition(_count, hit.point);
            RayCast(hit.point + reflectAngle, reflectAngle);
            return true;
        }

        if (hit == false)
        {
            _line.SetVertexCount(_count + 2);
            _line.SetPosition(_count + 1, position + direction * _maxDistance);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will test when i get home and give feedback.

Comment: Hello @Tedium Interactive. 
Thank you!! I tested your code and now I already have the line but I will have to make some adjustments. the aim line does not point in the direction of the gun and it also seems to me that the trajectory of the bullet is different from the trajectory of the aim line, right? 

Game Gif: https://ibb.co/MDsMRM0

Comment: Yes it looks like it @tigrev. The orientation of the first line is determined by `RayCast(transform.position, transform.up);` in the update function. You could probably change it to `RayCast(transform.position, transform.right);`. But it depends on the initial direction of the projectile.

Comment: That´s it! I change to  transform.right and now the aim line is pointing in the gun direction. 
My problem now is that the trajectory of the bullet fired is not the same as the aim line...    Game pic: https://ibb.co/4Y5vwGM

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed on the physics material of the bullet, the Friction to 0 and Bounciness to 1. Also on the rigidbody2D the linear drag, angular drag and gravity scale  all to 0.  Although it is not a perfect rebound it was very close to what I intend for the game. Thank you! Check it out: [Game Gif](https://ibb.co/dptxMdd)

Only negative thing is that my bullet is not turning in the direction of the movement after the rebound. I tried to use `transform.LookAt` but didn`t work. This is my bullet script:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public float speed = 20f;
 public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;


 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     this.myRigidbody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     this.myRigidbody.velocity = transform.right * speed;
     transform.LookAt(transform.position + this.myRigidbody.velocity);
 }
 }
```

But now i have this error: Error CS0034 Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'